# Cannot choose python version

Tags: python

I have both 3.6 and 3.7 installed and I want to change to 3.7. I followed instructions and installed them both as alternatives so that `update-alternatives --config python` gives me:

```
 Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         manual mode
```

As you can see, the `*` is in front of the 3.7 versions. From the instructions that I found, I understood that this is how I should select 3.7 version. However, `python --version` command still gives me `Python 3.6.8`. What could be wrong here?

Comment: You may need to restart the console after the change.

Comment: you can always use `python3.7` to run version 3.7

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: 1. I have restarted the terminal (in JupyterLab). 2. I am indeed using virtual environments with my projects but I tried `python --version` outside of project folder.